# Comparing hours from different time zones

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I need little bit help about comparing hours from different time zones. For the comparison i am using a UTC format for saving every hour for a specific date. My problem comes when there is DST and we have 25 hours instead of 24.

To be more clear what is exactly my problem, I will give an example:

1st Case: Let's say on Date X at 3 AM we have daylight saving time, so i will add a value for 1 am (UTC 00:00:00), for 2 am (UTC 01:00:00), at 3 am i need to turn back the clock so i will add a value again for 2 am and so on. The good thing is that i will have exactly 25 values for date X, the bad thing is that i have two values for 2 am, which is not correct.

2nd Case: As in the previous case I add a value for every hour. When it turns 3 am I continue to i will increment the date with one hour, that will cause me to push the last 25 hour in the next day (UTC 00:00:00). The bad thing is that for the date X I will have only 24 hours, which is not correct for my calculations, but from the good side I will have no duplicate hours.

How can I save my hourly values so I have on specific dates 25/23 hours without hourly duplicates ? The format must be easy, so later I can add timezone difference and compare these hours ?

Comment: "the bad thing is that i have two values for 2 am, which is not correct" - in what way isn't it correct? If 2am happens twice in reality, your data is mirroring reality. What's wrong with that? If you're storing UTC anyway, you won't have any duplicates or gaps.

Comment: (It's still not clear to me what you're asking, really. If you're using UTC, where do other time zones come in?)

Comment: The problem maybe comes from the storing in UTC. I have values for all calendar days, which i need to store. For date X i have value for 1st hour (00:00:00 - 01:00:00) and etc. I generate the first hour in UTC like that: $dt = new DateTime($date.' 00:00:00', new DateTimeZone("UTC")); and than the next hours i add like that: $dt->add(new DateInterval('PT1H')); The problem is i do not know what i need to do on the days where the DST changes. How i need to store the values ?

Comment: Converting *from* a local date *into* UTC is often a bad idea. Can you not keep *everything* in UTC from start to finish? You haven't really provided enough context here. Please edit the question to clarify it.

Comment: "the bad thing is that i have two values for 2 am, which is not correct" - this is not correct from the purpose of my calculations. I need to have one value for each hour and also exact number of hours 23/24/25 for the specific date.

Comment: Well that's exactly what you'll get if you store everything in UTC. If you need to find out the values for a specific *local* date, you need to then work out when it started in UTC and when it ended in UTC, then you can perform a query which will retrieve 23, 24 or 25 values. Every row will have a different time in UTC, but two rows may have a UTC value that would map to the same local time.

Comment: Maybe instead of storing UTC you can store a DateTimeOffset which contains both the local time and the offset to UTC. That way you can have a day with 23 or 25 hours, but can convert to UTC if needed.